# Cadastral Parcel Fabric

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, parcel, parcel-fabric

Does anyone know if there is a way to move a group of individual cadastral parcels as a block? I do not wish to merge the parcels.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.3. I want to move the parcels as a block so that I can snap to another set of parcels.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want to try the [Transform Parcels toolbar](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-parcels/transformingparcels.htm):

> The Transform Parcels toolbar can be used to provisionally move a
>   selection of parcels in the parcel fabric. For example, you can use
>   the Transform Parcels toolbar to move parcels so that they line up
>   with an underlying orthophoto. When transforming parcels, parcel
>   points can be snapped to and linked to existing control points.

This allows you to select a group of parcels and move or scale them as you see fit, the result being something that *looks* good, but which is not necessarily accurate.

Note ESRI's note (emphasis is mine):

> Note: **You would use the Transform Parcels toolbar when** adjusting
>   parcels to a control network using **the parcel fabric adjustment is not
>   feasible because of poor data quality**. With a good quality,
>   survey-accurate fabric, the parcel fabric adjustment should be used to
>   move or transform parcels to control.